# My Website is Accessible via domain.com/index.html but not with domain.com

Tags: webserver

I'm sorry for this stupid question, but I'm very new to hosting and domain things and I need help. My Website [PrepareHOW.org](http://PrepareHOW.org) is not accessible with PrepareHOW.org but can be visited via [Preparehow.org/index.html](http://Preparehow.org/index.html) How can I remove this error so that people can access my website with my domain url.

Comment: I can access it from your domain name without index.html

Comment: Thank you so much Saurabh. I think it was a cache problem. I visited my site with another browser and yes it is fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you using nginx as frontend of webserver just check config for this domain.
This lines need to add to config:

```
root  /path/to/site/root/folder;
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html$is_args$args;
}
```

Then restart nginx and check result!